# Can the existence of God be proved from mathematics?

Tags: logic, theology

This question of highest importance for everybody could not be answered in MO and will not be answered in Mathematics.SE. I can understand why the set-theorists there dive and attack it like vultures. I feel very sorry. Perhaps the prevailing understanding of logic and tolerance is here more suitable?

Background: Gödel proved the existence of God in a relatively complicated way using the positive and negative properties introduced by Leibniz and the axiomatic method  ("the axiomatic method is very powerful", he said with a faint smile). To formalize the idea of a positive property, Gödel introduced a positivity operator. Just as a predicate or property provides a truth-functional assignment to individuals. We say that Pos(F) is true if F is a positive property. Please look it up if you have not yet heard of:

http://www.stats.uwaterloo.ca/~cgsmall/ontology.html
http://userpages.uni-koblenz.de/~beckert/Lehre/Seminar-LogikaufAbwegen/graf_folien.pdf

Couldn't the following simple way be more effective (and wouldn't it be appropriate to count it as belonging to mathematics)?

1) The set of real numbers is uncountable.
2) Humans can only identify countably many words.
3) Humans cannot distinguish what they cannot identify.
4) Humans cannot well-order what they cannot distinguish.
5) The real numbers can be well-ordered. (This is a theorem of set-theory: E. Zermelo: "Beweis, daß jede Menge wohlgeordnet werden kann", Math. 
Ann. 59 (1904) 514-516)
6. If this is true, then there must be a being with higher capacities than any human. (It has been proved that humans cannot well-order the real numbers. No set-theoretically definable well-ordering of the continuum can be proved to exist from the Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms together with the axiom of choice and the
generalized continuum hypothesis by S. Feferman: "Some applications of the notions of forcing and generic Sets", Talk at the International Symposium on the Theory of Models, Berkeley, 1963)

QED

Comment: How in the world does this this contrived set of claims prove the existence of God? What do they even have to do with the idea of a divine being?

Comment: Georg Cantor, the founder of set theory proved the existence of infinite sets by means of the holy bible. He wrote 1883 in a letter to Lipschitz: "Exodus, cap. XV, v. 18, Dominus regnabit in infinitum (aeternum) et ultra". Further evidence for his idea of aktualized or completed infinity, he took from Augustinus: S. Augustin (De civitate Dei. lib. XII, cap. 19): Contra eos, qui dicunt ea, quae infinita sunt, nec Dei posse scientia comprehendi. (letter of 1886).

Comment: cont'd: And it is obvious that we must accept a super-human being, if something that no inhabitant of the material universe can do, can be proved to be doable. Whether we call that being God, is a matter of taste.

Comment: Background information like that needs to be in the question; that was sort of the point of the comment. And Latin also needs to be translated into English. (If you don't know the translation, you probably shouldn't be quoting it, since that suggests you don't know what it means.)

Comment: @Cody Gray: Dominus regnabit in infinitum (aeternum) et ultra". God rules in infinity (eternity) _and beyond_. Cantor took this as a proof for his infinities beyond infinity. But that does not directly touch my question.

Comment: Voting to close for the time being pending some cleanup and clarification of the concern. Keep in mind great questions are self-contained, and ask about some really specific problem encountered during your study of philosophy. Please consider using the [edit functionality](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/posts/2702/edit) to revise your post.

Comment: Euler’s proof: (a+bⁿ)/n = x, hence God exists.

Comment: The real numbers can be well ordered - the "<" relation, used in the definition of the real numbers, well-orders them. There is no god needed for the well-ordering, so that argument completely falls apart.

Comment: The real bummer in your argument is that you read the words of a mathematical theorem and assume a meaning that isn't there. "Every set can be well ordered" does NOT mean "for every set there is a being which can well-order the set".

Comment: I suppose one could say that anything can be proven via mathematical arguments (if it is true), and anything can be proven via religious arguments (irregardless of its truth or falsity); thus, mathematical proofs are a subset of religious proofs, and therefore one cannot prove the existence of God mathematically. And therefore it follows that we shouldn't waste time studying math when religion is so much more powerful. QED.

Comment: @gnasher729: The "<" relation does not well-order the real numbers. A set is well-ordered if every non-empty subset has a first element. What would be the first element of the positive real numbers?

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: Everything can be proven via mathematical arguments whether true or not. You need only introduce the axiom: {here insert what you like} exists.

Comment: @gnasher729: In science and mathematics the statement "every set can be well-ordered" would mean that everybody with enough education or training could do it.

Comment: @Heinrich: What?!? And there I thought I'd come up with a fool(?)-proof way to get out of studying math. DRAT!!!! :-)

Comment: See the Law of the Eternal at metagovernment.org.

Answer (score 7):

First of all: let's leave "God" out of this.  The argument offers no definition of God, or why one must exist-- but that's just the least of the problems.  In fact, the number of fallacies in the proposed syllogism is staggering.

There is *absolutely* no relevant distinction that can be drawn between "words" and "numbers" in terms of this argument.  The set of real numbers is an abstract set, as is the set of potential words.  Neither is countable, yet humans are capable of distinguishing between any two numbers or words, and ordering them according to numerical/alphabetical sequence.  And the capability of a human to do so for larger subsets is limited only by the time allotted.

Not only does the proposed argument have no bearing on whether or not God exists, it actually fails to prove **anything.**

Comment: Please inform yourself at least a little bit before trying to patronize. Of course the set of finite words is countable. And the set of nunbers, a subset of the former, is uncountable.

Comment: The set of finite words is countable, but the set of *potential* words is not-- and actual words, like actual numbers, only exist when identified.  I repeat: there is *no relevant distinction* between words and numbers in this regard.  Humans can only identify (or well-order) countably many real numbers, but the set of real numbers these instances are drawn from is uncountable-- and the same holds true for words.

Comment: Information and labelling requires finite words. Potential words could at most be used by God because it requires an infinite amount of bits to identify, express or communicate them.

Comment: The set of potential words, like the set of real numbers, is an abstraction.  There is no particular reason to believe that the numbers (or words) *exist* in any meaningful sense until they are actually used/identified.

Comment: By the way: the same holds true for the set of integers as well.

Comment: A set that has no existence cannot be well-ordered. The set of potential words is irrelevant for the present discussion. The set of real numbers is relevant, and all its elements must exist, if all can be well-ordered.

Comment: Its elements *must* exist?  The number of questions you are begging is overwhelming.  In any event, your "proof" still fails to prove anything, much less the existence of God, and you have done nothing thus far to change that.  As comments are not intended for extended discussion, I suggest we move this to chat, or leave it be.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by a 'potential word' (maybe some string of letters that may make sense or have meaning in a given language at some point?)... But to prove that the set of (english) words are uncountable, consider the following. Let's agree that the set of real numbers are uncountable (this can be looked up in any set theory or analysis book). Now consider the words used to refer to a given real number, for example the word 'one' is used to refer to the real number '1' or the words 'one half' and 'zero point five' is used to refer to the real number '1/2'.

Comment: It follows that for every real number there exists a word (maybe more) used to refer to that number. Thus there must be a surjective (onto) mapping from the set of real numbers to the set of words. This means that the cardinality of the set of words is greater than or equal to the cardinality of the set of real numbers (this principle can also be found in any set theory or real analysis book). Therefore, we can conclude that the set of words are uncountable. Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read the last comment... apologies!

Comment: @Alborz:Try to convince a mathematician of your theory. No, that is obviously wrong as every first semester student can show you. The set of finite words is countable. The set of real numbers is uncountable. But the set of _those real numbers that can be identified_ is a subset of the set of finite words i.e. finite strings of symbols.

Comment: @Michael: The elements of a set, all elements of which can be well-ordered, _must_ exist. How would you try to well-order non-existing entities?

Comment: @IKRus: I assume you haven't read much about Fictionalism in Mathematics, then.  And it seems to me you are willfully confusing the (finite) *act* of well-ordering, with the notion of an abstractly well-ordered set. In any event, further discussion appears to be fruitless.  We can take this to chat, or let it drop, but I don't want to further pollute the comments here.

Comment: @Michael Dorfman: My question remains, independent of name dropping like Fictionalism in Mathematics. Well-ordering an infinite set is not a finite act. But I am willing to switch to chat, if I am told how to do that.

Comment: @Alborz: I just saw an explanation of yours in another question: "Naively, we can see that the real numbers are uncountable, because between any two real numbers there is another real number." This explanation would apply to the rational numbers or the algebraic numbers too, naively. But they aren't. They are countable.

Comment: @AlborzYarahmadi - You can convert all your words into numbers and then you'll get a set of natural numbers, and then do Cantor diagonalization to produce something not in that set.  So in fact this shows that _almost all real numbers have infinitely long decimal expansions_, as otherwise you'd be able to represent them with (arbitrarily long) finite-length words.

Comment: Yes I see the mistake I had made... I assumed that there is a name/word for every real number. Upon second thought, I see that this isn't necessarily true. I also realize the previous comment I made about real numbers being uncountable because between any two real numbers there is another real number is an error. It's difficult to explain these concepts without being formal.

Comment: Since there is an unnecessary amount of rudeness in these comments, I'm sorry I got involved. I had an idea that I shared with decent intentions. @IKRus, maybe you are right in that a first semester student can show me this error but I doubt you could find any silly enough to make the argument you did in attempting to prove the existence of god from mathematics. Thank you for the pleasant conversation.

Answer (score 4):

Like the [ontological argument](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ontological-arguments/) and most arguments of this (*a priori*) nature, no matter how profound the logic is, the whole argument fails to have much real-world applicability.

First I would just like to point out that instead of ending your argument with "QED", it would be appropriate to end with an actual conclusion, as any conclusion which may appear obvious to you may not be as obvious to everyone else.

I'm no mathematician, but **it seems the flaw with your argument lies with premise 5**; I don't see how it is *intrinsically* true that the real numbers can be well-ordered. Real numbers can only be well-ordered insofar as we possess the ability to identify them. That is, if you admit the set of real numbers cannot be counted (premise 1), then you must admit that the set of real numbers cannot be well-ordered.

**But let's just say this argument was without error,** that it was through and through quite sound. The next problem is that the reasoning you offer doesn't get us anywhere; it doesn't imply God must exist at all. Period. *At best* it would imply "a thing" did "something" to make this math work; that thing needn't be a God and wouldn't even necessarily exist today.

Comment: You are quite right when you say: "Real numbers can only be well-ordered insofar as we possess the ability to identify them". But modern mathematics is proud to have proved the contrary (Zermelo, 1904). Hence, if modern mathematics is not wrong, then there must be a "something" that can do the well-ordering. I call it God. How would you call it?

Comment: @IKRus I would call it the axiom of choice.

Comment: The axiom does nothing. Either the axiom lies or the mathematicians who "proved": every set _can be well-ordered_.

Comment: How would we even _have_ a real number yet not be able to identify it?  I think you're accepting part of the argument that isn't logically sound, namely that there is actually something around that needs identification.  This is true for a backgammon set, but not hypothetical members of uncountably infinite sets.

Comment: We cannot _have_ a real number that is not identified - at least as the solution of an equation like "2x + 3 = e". But set theory is based upon the belief that there are more real numbers than can be identified by finite strings of symbols like the one above.

Comment: The real numbers are well-ordered with the "<" relation. They are well-ordered by definition. They have no choice but to be well-ordered.

Answer (score 3):

You're playing word-games with "identify" and "distinguish".

> Humans can only identify countably many words.

In one sense this is true, because if you ask me to identify a particular word, I need a finite representation of it.  But in another sense we can't even identify *countably* many words; I have finite lifetime and memory and so on, so it seems implausible that I could even check whether two 10<sup>80</sup> character long words were the same.  And in another sense we can identify uncountably many words by, for example, rules that tell us whether or not a word belongs to some set.  The words then need not be finite in length or in a countable set; we can't necessarily *manually* check their properties or identity, but we can manipulate finite sets of rules that describe them.

So already by (2) you're mired in ambiguity, and this sinks the argument when you get to (4) and (5), where in (4) you use a limited sense of identify and in (5) you implicitly use an expansive one.

Incidentally, point (3) is either false or adds absolutely nothing: if we encrypt each of our user names, I'll be able to tell that they are different (distinguish) without being able to tell which is which (identify).  Or if by "distinguish" you mean "check the equivalence relation of", that's *exactly* what you have to do to identify something.  So you're not even using a different concept here.  "Humans cannot well-order items whose equivalence relation they cannot check."  (This is true, but you still have the check-by-hand vs. check-using-logic dichotomy that sunk point (2).)

Comment: You say: "we can't even identify countably many words". That is true, but you can identify each of them. "And in another sense we can identify uncountably many words by, for example, rules that tell us whether or not a word belongs to some set." That is not true. In order to decide whether a word belongs to some set, this very word must be _given_. Therefore it must be encoded by a sequence of symbols that can be communicated in finite time.

Comment: @IKRus - You can use a description that is different than the definition in the set.  For example, "the ratio of the circumference to the diameter of a circle" is not infinitely long, even though the decimal representation of that number is infinitely long.

Comment: In fact there are many, many definitions for pi, one of them you have quoted. Other involve the definition of infinite series (Gregory-Leibniz, Euler) infinite products (Vieta, Wallis) sequnces and modular identities. In fact there are infinitely many words, each one defining pi. But there are many more real numbers without any finite definition.

Comment: @IKRus - Indeed.  But who cares?  You can still do mathematics.  If you mean that for real numbers to _actually physically exist_ (not just as a logical construct that we've made), we'd need _something_ different than our known physical reality, yes, of course.  But there's no evidence they do exist, so that doesn't get you anywhere either.

Comment: Of course we can do mathematics like before Cantor. But _if there are uncountably many reals that can be well-ordered_ (not in the real universe - that is impossible, even if the universe is an infinite multiverse), then only God can do so. Who else? No inhabitant of the infinite universe accomplish that. Modern set theory proves both statements (look into the literature given in my question). Therefore it either proves a contradiction or it proves God (or a comparable being).

Comment: @IKRus - Give me any two real numbers and I'll tell you which one is greater.  That's all a well-ordering says: `∀x∀y(x<y || y<x || x==y)`.  Unless the numbers are actual physical objects, it's not like you have to move every single one into place.  (You're confusing what is known in functional programming terms as "lazy" and "strict" evaluation.  They're logically equivalent, but the latter might require an uncountably infinite amount of work.)

Comment: If I "give" you a number, then I define it such that you know it. But I can only give you numbers with finite definition. All real numbers that can be "given" belong to a countable set.

Comment: @IKRus - I am claiming that well-ordering means no more than that when presented with any pair of numbers, you could make a decision.  This is the whole point of using variables!  You don't have to actually _do_ everything, just show how it can be done in general.

Comment: Well-ordering has nothing to do with magnitude and pairs. Well-ordering the set of real numbers |Rmeans: Every non-empty subset of the set |R has a first element (according to the chosen order). If this is required for uncountably many numbers, then it must be possible that uncountably many can "be given". That is not the case for humans.

Comment: @IKRus - Er, right, the above is only equivalent for finite sets.  Anyway, you're still making a really fundamental mistake of the lazy/strict or conceptual/actual type.  You seem to deny that I can say "all numbers that end in 6 are even" without having a god around to produce all the numbers.

Comment: You are right. But by that you define only a set of numbers, i.e. a subset of the set of even numbers. You cannot well-order the elements of that set as individuals. But that would be required by Zermelo's theorem. Compare the difference between knowing the title of a book and knowing its contents.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. Mathematics can't prove the existence of anything.

How math corresponds to reality is a question for the [philosophy of mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics). There are many theories. Some believe that numbers exists and others believe they don't exist. Some believe in mathematical truth while others believe mathematical truth is fictional. Some believe that math exists in minds, others believe it exists in a Platonic realm. A lot of philosophers and mathematicians simply don't care!

Mathematical infinite order might exist but before you call that "God" maybe you should ask the theologians about it?

Comment: In any case, if numbers can be well-ordered, they must exist. I have also asked in Christianity.SE. But the mathematics there is on low level.

Comment: If Superman can be stronger than batman he must exist, right? We all know that Superman is stronger than batman.

Comment: Of course superman exists, namely as an idea that can be put in some order with respect to batman - just like every real number.

Comment: Now I'll go teach my children that batman is stronger than superman. Ideas are subjective. Gödel believed in objective math, independent of minds.

Comment: Ideas are subjective, poems, pictures, inventions. Numbers are ideas too, but they have a more objective status. If you teach your children 10 < 3, they will get in trouble sometime.

Comment: Alright. If you believe that numbers are ideas you should add that to your proof. Then it makes sense.

Comment: What do you think that numbers are?